# Fetching owner-uploaded or user-uploaded photos from Google Maps

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, panoramio

I would like to fetch user-uploaded or owner-uploaded photos of locations using some Google API.

For example:
In this place: http://g.co/maps/pxbse , you can see an owner-uploaded photo of this place in the place's popup window on the map. Additionally, if you click on this photo, you'll be taken to a more detailed page about this place where you can see a list of photos uploaded either by the owner or other google users.

Is there any way to fetch these photos by using the Google Maps API?

(Please note: I have checked out Panoramio and Google Street View API and these do not suit my needs)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at is a Google Place.  You would access this data using the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/).

**Update**: You're right.  The API mentions an icon URL that's included in a [place details response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceDetailsResponses), but doesn't seem to indicate all the owner uploaded images.

What I recommend is attending the [Google Maps API office hours](https://plus.google.com/u/0/104063627743574070634/posts/EiZUgx8PgR1) on May 1, 2012 at 13:00 Pacific Time.  There is a [Google Moderator set up](http://www.google.com/moderator/#15/e=1f9e7b&t=1f9e7b.46&f=1f9e7b.652fef) to post questions before hand.  You can attend the hangout using Google Plus (make sure to follow +Google Maps API) or they stream them to YouTube live.

Comment: I know, the thing is, as much as I've searched the Google Places API I couldn't find a way to fetch these photos I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get that photo at this point. The Google Places API does not support retrieving the photo.